# Save a list that is read/loaded

Tags: c

\I'm creating a shopping/grocery list that should be able to save and load .txt files, where you also should be able to edit/delete items AFTER you have loaded an already saved file. I am currently facing a dilemma where I can't save changes in the loaded/read .txt file.

For example, if I load an already created .txt file with, lets say, carrots and potatoes and I want to remove potatoes, I am unable to. The program only states that the list is "empty".

So I'm asking how to save changes in a .txt file that I have loaded, because I can't figure it out at all.

This is my code for the load function:

```
void loadList(struct ShoppingList* list){
int i;
FILE *fileHandler;
char filename[256];

printf("Enter the filename to open \n");
scanf("%s", filename);

fileHandler = fopen(filename, "r");           
if (fileHandler == NULL)
{
    printf("Error! \n");
    return;
}

for (i = 1; fgets(filename, sizeof(filename), fileHandler) != NULL; i++)
{
    printf("%s", filename);
}

fclose(fileHandler);                       
return 0;
}
```

Ask if you want to see the function where I save .txt files and I will link it in a comment!

Comment: we need to see a [mcve].

Comment: is this your full code ?? provide more details

Comment: `if(fileHandler == NULL) { perror(filename); ... }` . Error messages matter.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of alternatives:

- The first is to simply load all of the file into memory, storing each line in a container-like structure (array, list, etc.) and do the modification on the data in memory. Then save all of the data back into the file.
- Another alternative is to read line by line (much like you do now) and rewrite to a *temporary* file. When you reach the specific line you want to modify do the modification and save it to the temporary file. Continue to read the remaining lines and save them to the temporary file. Once all lines have been read, rename the temporary file as the original file.